# Openxml word insert image

Tags: image, base64, overlay, openxml

I have an excel sheet converted to html, then HTML converted to word. There is one missing thing: images from excel sheet are in format of base64 string and they are overlay on table, not a part of cell. How can I add such images to my docx file? 
I want an image overlay on table starting over a special cell (like E18).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Base64 string must be converted to memorystream to be used as image source

```
ImagePart imgp = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
MemoryStream M = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(o.Base64String));
imgp.FeedData(M);
```

2- Drawing object with anchor must be created to accommodate the image. Inline drawing is not useful. Anchor object helps flow image above text to any place.

3- Most samples on  the net add the drawing to document or body or run.... For purpose of my question (reference point inside of cell), we easily add drawing to cell object.

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/33a7618d-21c2-47ea-9125-b7c7497f17e3/word-document-anchor-relative-to-table-cell?forum=oxmlsdk) post shows adding drawing to cell object. [This](http://www.ludovicperrichon.com/create-a-word-document-with-openxml-and-c/) post shows use of Anchor object.